# Audio raw data format in Gstreamer?

Tags: audio, buffer, gstreamer

im trying to create a visualizer with Gstreamer 1.0.

When I get the raw audio data from the pipeline in the format of a GstBuffer,
and then the Buffer is mapped with `gst_buffer_map`,
the corresponding `map.data` ([link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstMemory.html#GstMapInfo))
is of format guint8, so it is between 0 and 255. The map size is slightly above 4000.

How can I interpret these values? How are the audio frequencies contained within them?
I would be very thankful for a helpful answer.

regards,
tagelicht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an appsink and calling `gst_app_sink_set_caps()` on it during the creation to set up the format that will be received on it.

There is also `gst_app_sink_get_caps()`.